# libpython3.10 : Depends: libpython3.10-stdlib (= 3.10.4-3ubuntu0.1) but 3.10.6-1+focal1 is to be installed (Ubuntu 22.04 missing settings)

Tags: apt, dependencies, 22.04, gnome-control-center

Fresh from upgrading from Ubuntu 20.04 to 22.04, the Gnome-control-center (settings) was missing. I could not find anyone who resolved this specific issue.

I tried installing gnome-control-center `sudo apt install gnome-control-center`, which returned the following output:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libpython3.10 : Depends: libpython3.10-stdlib (= 3.10.4-3ubuntu0.1) but 3.10.6-1+focal1 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Solution:

As indicated in the error output there is a broken package **libpython3.10-stdlib**:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libpython3.10 : Depends: libpython3.10-stdlib (= 3.10.4-3ubuntu0.1) but 3.10.6-1+focal1 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

1. Manually remove the broken package, **libpython3.10-stdlib**, with `sudo apt remove libpython3.10-stdlib`
2. Run `sudo apt --fix-broken install`. In my case, the output after running this command prompted the following 'Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.', so next I ran `sudo apt autoremove`
3. Run `sudo apt update` and then `sudo apt upgrade`.
4. Install gnome-control-center with `sudo apt install gnome-control-center`.

You should now be able to launch the application by running `gnome-control-center`, the 'Settings' icon should also be displayed in your application panel.

Comment: I have the same problem, but unfortunately your solution doesnt fix it for me. In my case I want to install `sudo apt install obs-studio` and get the same error as above: `The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libpython3.10-stdlib : Depends: libpython3.10-minimal (= 3.10.6-1~22.04.2) but 3.10.10-1+focal1 is to be installed` ...